# Directly use upsert to hbase table through Phoenix View

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have question related to hbase tables map to phoenix.
Is that possible to use 'upsert' directly to the view hbase tables on phoenix?
Because when i tried to do that, i faced error that said 'table is read only'.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation :

> A view will be updatable (i.e. referenceable in a DML statement such
>   as UPSERT or DELETE) if its WHERE clause expression contains only
>   simple equality expressions separated by ANDs. Updatable views are not
>   required to set the columns which appear in the equality expressions,
>   as the equality expressions define the default values for those
>   columns.

Another option is , creating a table referencing the existing hbase table. You can use upserts with that.